# how to get multiple network names using get-networkadapter CMDLET?

Tags: powershell

Am new to Powershell. I need to get names of all network using `get-networkadapter cmdlet`.  Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: What get-networkadapter cmdlet? This is not a shipping cmdlet with powershell. It's a 3rd party cmdlet - find out who wrote it, and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI to do this:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapater -Filter "NetEnabled=$true"
```

will list the network adapter details. If you want to look at the IP address details, you can do so by:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=$true"
```